# Facebook AppInvite Android Studio Cannot resolve method show(

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, react-native

I'm developping an app with react native, but I need to incorporate a native module to use the Facebook AppInvite to let user invite friends on my app.

However, I've followed everything in the react native's documentation to add a native module in react native (the link between react native and native code works), but the native module written in java doesn't work.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

```
package com.App.App;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.share.model.AppInviteContent;
import com.facebook.share.widget.AppInviteDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FacebookInviteModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    //Cannot be modified since it use by reactnative
    public FacebookInviteModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    //Cannot be modified since it use by reactnative
    @Override
         public String getName() {
         return "FacebookInvite";
    }

    @ReactMethod

    public void showModule(){

        String appLinkUrl, previewImageUrl;

        appLinkUrl = "https://www.app.com/myapplink";
        previewImageUrl = "https://www.app.com/my_invite_image.jpg";

        if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
            AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                    .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                    .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                    .build();

            AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing can be pass in the function showModule() since it is use in the javascript code to show the native component as it is called like this in react native : NativeModules.FacebookInvite.showModule();

For the code in the function showModule(), I'm using exactly the same code as on the official documentation of Facebook : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android

But I get an error with :
     AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
saying that "Cannot resolve method 'show(com.App.App.FacebookInviteModule, com.facebook.share.model.AppInviteContent)"

I quite know ReactNative, but I don't know much with Java and I don't understand the error.
The file code is in the same folder than the MainActivty and MainApplication.

So if anyone know what I can do to make this it work, it would be wonderful :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write a native component. You can use official facebook library for App Invites. react-native-fbsdk has [AppInvite Component](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/js/FBAppInviteDialog.js). Its not well documented but has pretty much all the explanation you need inside the code files. Check the source code and you can easily figure it out.

**Example**

```
import { AppInviteDialog } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

AppInviteDialog.canShow().then(()=> {
    AppInviteDialog.show({
        previewImageUrl,
        applinkUrl,
        promotionCode,
        promotionText
    }).then(() => { ... });
}).catch(()=> { console.error('App invite can't show!'); });
```

Comment: Thank you so much bennygenel !!! It worked ! it's a pity that de react-native-fbsdk is very well documented.